# gtest in eclipse error:ld.exe can not find -llibgtest

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, mingw, googletest

I use google test(gtest) in eclipse, here's my code

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_
int Foo(int a, int b);
#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "test.h"
int Foo(int a, int b) {

return a + b;}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"


TEST(FooTest, HandleNoneZeroInput)
{

    EXPECT_EQ(2, Foo(4, 10));

    EXPECT_EQ(6, Foo(30, 18));

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

here's my eclipse configuration:

```
Library Paths    F:\GTEST\googletest\googletest\mybuild\lib


Libraries        libgtest


Includes         F:\GTEST\googletest\googletest\include
```

there are two files in my folder `F:\GTEST\googletest\googletest\mybuild\lib` which named `libgtest.a` and `libgtest_main.a`

I build my project and eclipse produces an error:

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibgtest`

Note:

My work environment is `windows7_64, mingw32, gcc 6.3.0, eclipse`

thank you and I wish your solutions.

Comment: i solve this problem, but i get another problem

Comment: these's many error such as "undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. "lib"  prefix should be omitted when libraries are listed in the Libraries section of Eclipse configuration:

```
Libraries        gtest gtest_main
```

Comment: thank you ,i solve this problem, but i get this problem:

Comment: these's many error such as "undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'"

Comment: Add gtest_main to libraries.

Comment: i add gtest_main to library，but it still this error，

Comment: thank you , i solve this problem , i restart my eclipse ,it's workd，hh